# fit gaussian function to a broad data

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two Arrays.  one is E which is an integer Array from 0-21. the second is E_Dist which Shows the number of elements for each index of E Array. the  min and max values of E_Dist is 0-450000.

I want to plot E_Dist  vs E, i.e E in horizontal and  E_Dist  in vertical direction and fit a  gaussian function to this plot.
unfortunately How much I try I cannot fit a gaussian function to it. I have some Problems in fact:

1- how can I guess the Center of gaussian function correctly. I can use simply the mean value of E, which is 10, but in reality my gaussian plot Peaks about 5. I tried to use some formula like

E_cen= sum(E*E_Dist)/sum(E)

but now the result is much worse and is about 10e4.

2- I used two different gaussian function form one with Amplitude and another without it. I never could fit a gaussian function when I considered the Amplitude  but without Amplitude  I have a gaussian  plot but never fit my data Points.

I think one issue is that I couldn't calculate the Sigma or other gaussian Parameters correctly. another one can be the large difference of E_Dist values which covers 0 to 450000.

I attached my plotanyone can help me how can I solve the Problem?

Thanks in advance
.[image]

```
########### Gaussian fit

  E_cen= np.mean(E)
  print 'E_cen=',E_cen  
  10.54
  mean_N = np.mean(E_Dist )         # mean number of particles
  print 'mean_N=',mean_N
  >>>58937

  sigma = np.sqrt( sum((E_Dist - mean_N)**2 )/len(E_Dist)-1 )             
  print 'sigma =',sigma   #/1.e9,'*1.e9'
  >>>119888.7


##########

 # def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
  #  return  a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))    # Gaussian function with amplitude
  #popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,E,E_Dist ,p0=[2,E_cen,sigma]) #


  def gaus(x,x0,sigma):
    return np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
  popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,E,E_Dist ,p0=[E_cen,sigma])          # no amplitude
  #################  
  print 'min(popt)=',min(popt)
  >>>10.54
  print 'max(popt)=',max(popt)
  >>>119800      
  print 'mean(popt)=',np.mean(popt)
  >>>59940
```

Comment: You should fit with an amplitude. If you don't get a converging fit, that's just because your initial parameters are too far off, or your assumption that your data is Gaussian is incorrect.

Comment: Are the red points the distribution of your data that you want to fit against? Can we safely ignore the blue points?

Comment: I have to fit with a gaussian function. I already did for previous Analysis. exactly one of my question is that how can I define the Initial values. In the code you can see I tried but it seems they are not correct. I used the Standard formula for defining Sigma but  it doesn't work.

Comment: Your sigma estimate is way off (if I'm correct about the red points being your data). You should instead calculate the spread in the E values as your starting point: you want the spread in E (x), not in E_Dist (y) as your sigma parameter.

Comment: yes the red points Show the gaussian distribution

Comment: Well, if the red points extend all the way to 21, then it's not really Gaussian distributed. It *could* be to a point: truncated on the lower side at 0. Which you could implement in your function if you wanted.

Comment: in fact E is a simple integer Array from 0 to 21 , i.e. 0,1,2, ....21.

Comment: If you want to estimate starting parameters using your y-values as weight, you can do, but you'll need to use your variables the other way around. Thus, e.g., `E_cen= sum(E*E_Dist)/sum(E_Dist)`, since your Gaussian parameters are along the *x-axis*, and similar (weighted) for sigma. your calculations for `E_cen` and `sigma` use the y-values as the main data, hence you get incorrect starting values. In fact, using the correct data and weights, your starting parameters are likely your best-fit parameters as well.

Comment: the Point is tha now I have                                                                E_cen= 4.59252216986,
sigma = 6.2928607617,

min(gaus(E,*popt))= -3.46382326073,
max(gaus(E,*popt))= 779.167147508,
mean(gaus(E,*popt)) = 387.851662124                                                                                            but still I cann't fit the data

Comment: max, min and mean of popt mean little, especially the mean. popt[0] is simply your best-fit E_cen, and popt[1] is your best-fit sigma. The reason E_cent is negative, is likely because of the long tail on the positive side; the fit compensates for that by assuming a negative tail as well. See my comment about the truncated Gaussian.